# Problem with creating an apk file using Buildozer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

[image: Screenshot]There is a problem with creating an apk file using Buildozer.  I get this error:

`# Command failed: /home/mi/buildozer-env/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create —dist_name=myapp —bootstrap=sdl2 —requirements=python3,kivy —arch armeabi-v7a —copy-libs —color=always —storage-dir="/home/mi/Desktop/egg/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" —ndk-api=21`

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The error says it tried to run autoreconf but couldn't find it, so try installing it.

Comment: I intstalled autoreconf (Guided by this: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/dh-autoreconf), but the problem was not solved